# How to get all contacts from phone and display in listview on button click in android?

Tags: android, listview

I want to fetch all Contacts from phone and simply display in android `ListView`, without store in database,the purpose is that when user click on button "sync all contacts" then ALL contacts should be fetched and show in `ListView`. Here is the main activity class i have also created getter-setter class with variable `contacts_name` and `phone_no`, and `CustomAdapter`class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
Button sync;



ArrayList<newlist> listitem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listitem = new ArrayList<newlist>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);

    sync= (Button) findViewById(R.id.syncID);
    sync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

              //what method will be used here for sync contacts and display in listview
           }
       });
   }
}
```

please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this library, you can get all contacts easily.

https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers

For the `ListView`, you need to write a custom adapter, you can also find a lot of examples on the internet. It is just a sample.

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private final Context context;
private ViewHolder holder;
private final ArrayList<Person> persons;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> persons) {
    super(context,0, persons);
    this.context = context;
    this.persons = persons;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return persons.size();
}

@Override
public Person getItem(int position) {
    return persons.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return persons.get(position).hashCode();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.personImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_image);
        holder.personNameLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_name_label);
        holder.personAddressLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_address_label);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else{
        //Get viewholder we already created
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Person person = persons.get(position);
    if(person != null){
        holder.personImage.setImageResource(person.getPhotoId());
        holder.personNameLabel.setText(person.getName());
        holder.personAddressLabel.setText(person.getAddress());

    }
    return convertView;
}

//View Holder Pattern for better performance
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView personNameLabel;
    TextView personAddressLabel;
    ImageView personImage;

}
}
```

In  **onCreate** read the library's documentation and try to figure out how you can get contacts.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // GET CONTACTS DATA
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.person_list_view);
    listViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,persons);
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Pls Write me the mainactivity code on button click method @eminuluyol

Comment: Hope you give the permission in your Manifest.xml  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

Answer (score 1):

Use below method to fetch contacts from phone's database(update the method according to your requirements, it currently fetches only contact numbers).

```
    List<Integer> fetchContacts() {
        final String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        };

        final Cursor phone = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);

        List<Integer> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        while(phone.moveToNext()){
            contacts.add(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER););
        }
        phone.close();
        return contacts;
    }
```

After that, you can pass this list of contacts to the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter to reflect the changes in the listview.

Also, you need to declare `uses-permission` for contacts permission in the manifest file like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: it gives error on context and return contacts, please write me full code also attach my code mainactivity i am new here thanks @Gaurav Chauhan